# How to check the state of a process controlled by Supervisor in Python

Tags: python, supervisord

I've set up Supervisor and have it monitoring some apps. Now I would like to use python to check the state of the monitored app and display it in my UI.

I would rather not do something like

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['supervisorctl', 'status app'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
status = p.communicate()[0].split()[1]
print status
```

Is there a way to do this with any supervisor python API?

Comment: whats wrong with that ? I guess you could put it in a function and call it an api...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I'm assuming there is already an API in python for this that I could leverage. `import supervisor` works but calling dir on it reveals nothing interesting.

Comment: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/supervisor/supervisorctl.py